# Does it matters if we swap the position of random variables appearing in the expression?

Tags: conditional-probability

Recall P(A AND B) = P(A|B)P(B) = P(B|A)P(A). Mathematically, it seems as long as all the terms in the expression is given, the position of A and B doesn't matter much. (i.e. the line defining which variable acts as 'condition' is blurred). However, logically sometimes it doesn't make sense. E.g. when the ground of the street is wet, it is because of raining. Here, P(wet|rain) defined but P(rain|wet) not, so I highly doubt how can 'P(A AND B) = P(A|B)P(B) = P(B|A)P(A)' stand in this case? Or it would stand all the time as long as the number of each term is given, without consideration to the logic of the true application? Or it's just me getting the whole thing wrongly? Please advise and thanks.

Comment: The probability of it raining given that the ground is wet depends on how often the ground gets wet for other reasons. You are trying to understand a general principle by only allowing it to work within a misconception of how reality works, and then wondering why the math doesn't make sense in that reality (when reality is irrelevant to whether the math works anyway).

Comment: Suppose you already knew $P(A \mid B)=0.8, P(B)=0.3, P(A)=0.4$ where $A$ was "street is wet" and $B$ was "it is raining".  Then you could work out that $P(A \text{ and } B)=0.24$ and $P(B \mid A)=0.6$ and have a fully consistent set of values.

Comment: @Nij, thank you for your answering. Can you please apply the logic of what you just said and answer the question 'Here, P(wet|rain) defined but P(rain|wet) not, so I highly doubt how can 'P(A AND B) = P(A|B)P(B) = P(B|A)P(A)' stand in this case?' directly please?

Comment: @Henry, excellent answer! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Both of things are defined, if you are in this reality. Your reality already rejected one of them, so, of course you are confused about why.

Comment: @Nij, thanks for the substantiation. I see you now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Here, P(wet|rain) defined but P(rain|wet) not, so I highly doubt how can 'P(A AND B) = P(A|B)P(B) = P(B|A)P(A)' stand in this case?

Probability does not imply a causality relation. P(wet|rain) gives a probability that something is wet, given that it rained. P(rain|wet) is the probability that it rained, provided that something is wet - e.g., you go out into the street and see that the pavement is wet, which could be because it rained during the night or because the street was washed by a cleaning truck.